# Why did the crew act violently?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the episode *Sarek*, ambassador Sarek (and his wife and aides) come aboard the Enterprise, which is to host a Federation-joining conference with some aliens. Geordie and Wesley install a pool for the aliens, who are presumably aquatic (amusingly, Sarek reports they are [offended by furniture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igFkYJ_XeOY)). I say aquatic, but the pool is filled with some weird gloopy fluid rather than water. Wesley says it stinks, but Geordie can't smell it (not unusual, there are several terrestrial smells and tastes, such as coriander, that are perceived differently between people according to genetics).

Anyway, during the episode crewmembers of the Enterprise are subject to sporadic moods of violence. Picard, following hints from Sarek's meddling aides, concludes Sarek, in his old age, is leaking repressed Vulcan emotions across the ship. Is the diagnosis ever confirmed? Dr Crusher suggests a medical test, but doesn't do it!

I have a different theory. Observe that every fight happens in either Wesley or Geordie's presence

1. Wesley and Geordie fight at the pool (over girls). This is the first fight.
2. Beverly slaps her son Wesley
3. The bar brawl (Geordie is drinking on the adjacent table)
4. Picard and Riker argue on the bridge (Wesley is just below them at his desk)

Perhaps the alien fluid induces violence in humans. It is volatile, so could saturate to Wesley and Geordie's clothes, and so be carried around the ship. What do you think?

Comment: It's been quite a while since I've seen it, but [Memory Alpha's plot summary](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Sarek_(episode)) implies Crusher did perform the test:  `She says that they can test for Bendii Syndrome but the results of the test to confirm it will not be available before the scheduled meeting with the Legarans.` (I mean, given the nature of Bendii Syndrome, it's not as though they'd just avoid it...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The episode makes it very clear that it was indeed Sarek's Bendii Syndrome that caused the fights (though oddly enough, none of his other emotions are projected onto crew members). For one, they observe Sarek crying during the concert, which could not have happened unless either Sarek has lost his ability to control his emotions or he has chosen to become a V'tosh ka'tur. Considering that Sarek still treats emotional expressions as taboo and continues to deny his emotionality throughout the episode, this clearly rules out the second possibility. He acts very much like an early Alzheimer's patient who's in denial about his failing mental faculties rather than someone who's chosen to embrace a radical new way of thinking.

Furthermore:

- Sarek's wife and his aids all try to hide Sarek to prevent his Bendii Syndrome being discovered; one of the aids even admits that he's been secretly helping Sarek maintain emotional composure;
- Sarek's wife mentions that he hasn't been able to meditate in a long time;
- when Picard confronts Sarek about his loss of emotional control, about his aid having had to psychically help him suppress his emotions, about his crying at the concert, etc. he has an emotional outburst which dispels all doubts (including Sarek's own denial) about Sarek's illness;
- Picard has to mind-meld with Sarek to help Sarek complete the negotiations, during which Picard experiences Sarek's emotional turmoil for him, again proving beyond all doubt that Sarek has lost his emotional control;
- Sarek and his entourage eventually admit that Sarek has Bendii syndrome, and his illness is further explored in a later episode when he eventually dies from it.

All of these facts contradict and are impossible to reconcile with your theory.